# Not able to execute selenium test cases via Azure Devops release pipeline

Tags: azure, selenium, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to configure and run selenium test cases from Azure Devops Release pipeline. I did configure Visual studio Test Platform installer followed by Visual studio test. However, while running the 'test task', its erroring out stating

```
2019-12-22T11:31:50.7602521Z ##[warning]No test sources found matching the given filter '**\*csproj'
```

Am I missing something here or not doing proper configuration?

My main test case is being written in .cs file and tried including it in path as well but still same error.

Can someone please guide me?

thanks,
Pankaj

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SO club. Try to update your question and make it a bit more clear. Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the path to the assemblies - `dll`. `cs` files are not used here as they are not compiled.
Provide the search pattern in the *Test files* field [image]
Example search pattern:

```
**\publish\Test.Project.Name.dll
!**\*TestAdapter.dll
!**\obj\**
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. which DLL should i specify. In my current Test repository which i received from QA team, can see only files which are .cs or .csproj. Also I see a config file followed by chrome driver.  Please note that am new to this testing arena so please excuse if my questions are still very basic.

Comment: You have to find the dll that has the same name as the testing project (csproj). If you are using Visual Studio, you will find the dll in the `C:\ProjectFolder\obj\Debug\\` or `C:\ProjectFolder\obj\Release\\`

Answer (score 0):

Have you built your project? Since you said you can see only files which are .cs or .csproj. You should first build your project to generate .dll files which are used in your vstest test files.

You can add the Visual Studio Build Task above the Visual Studio Test Task, then choose your project(.csproj or .sln) in the Solution Tag.

[image]

After building, you will see the .dll files in your Artifact, then, as Jonah said, you need to specify the location of the .dll file in Test files.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. I did updated build pipeline to include the required DLLs for testing. and now in the release pipeline, can invoke those DLL's. However am curious to understand how  can I set URL to the endpoint against which those DLL's will run?

Comment: All right. Ihave made some progress. Followed above steps mentioned by mj1313. While executing the Selenium testcases from Visual Studio test, getting below message. Any idea how can this be sorted out                                     .2019-12-30T10:48:29.2449208Z FabrikamFiber.SeleniumTests.dll is built for Framework 4.6.1 and Platform AnyCPU.
2019-12-30T10:48:29.2449260Z Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll is built for Framework 4.5 and Platform AnyCPU.

Comment: Can you build the test locally?

Comment: Yes I can. Was able to run test cases via visual studio.

Comment: OK, you can change the Visual Studio Version to make it the same as your local, and if it still doesn't work, please show us the detail error message

Comment: The issue has been resolved now. one of my colleague helped me in getting this sorted. they explicitly added "/Framework:.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 /Platform:x64" in "Other Console Options" and was able to execute selenium test cases.

Comment: The issue has been sorted now. Can we close this or I need to do something from my side.